# Adding a column to a table (using jQuery) makes the table larger, why?

Tags: jquery, css, width

I'm building a table data editor, and need functionality that's not available in the ready-built plugins. This is my code so far:

http://sandman.net/test/tables.php

But I'm having problem with my "add column" ("Lägg till kolumn") button, which correctly adds a column, but makes the table one column larger in the process. I've even tried to set the TD widths to percentages after the fact but it doesn't work.

How do I add a column and make it automatically resize all columns for it to fit in the preset width?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nice work you have there.I'm wondering is the re-adjusting of the existing column width still in effect? It seems like it is not.

I ran these in firebug, the table never gets widen after that:

```
$('.editgrid td input').css('width','100%');
$('.editgrid ').css('width','100%');
$('.editgrid td.gridvalue').css('width','25%');  //use (100 / datacolumn count) % instead
$('.editgrid td.controller').css('width','7px');
```

Hope this can help you to find your solution.

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what part of that that did the trick, but it worked as advertised. Thanks a million!

Comment: @Sandman: What did the trick is obvious, the textboxes in the cells are fixed width, it forced the resizing of the cell, hence the columns and the table. No matter how you try to make the cells narrower, will not work :)

Answer (score 0):

What you could do is set new widths for each column in Javascript as you add a column.

```
// Get current column count
var columnCount = $('table').children();

// Calculate new column width
var columnWidth = 100 / (columnCount + 1);

// Apply width to each column
$('table').children().each(row, function() {
    row.style.width = columnWidth + 'px';
}
```

I never work with jQuery so I hope the syntax is right. Your editor looks great btw ;-)

Comment: As I mentioned in my OP, I've already tried that, and it didn't work.